Laravel 11 not automatically registering policy
Laravel documentation says that laravel automatically registers policies when using correct naming and folder structure, but my policies are not registered. I have tried to view project detail with user that does not own the project and it works, but the function in policy returns false.
/app/Policies/ProjectPolicy.php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Project;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

class ProjectPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     */
    public function viewAny(?User $user): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     */
    public function view(User $user, Project $project): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     */
    public function create(?User $user): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     */
    public function update(User $user, Project $project): bool
    {
        return $user->id === $project->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Project $project): bool
    {
        return $user->id === $project->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can restore the model.
     */
    public function restore(?User $user, ?Project $project): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can permanently delete the model.
     */
    public function forceDelete(?User $user, ?Project $project): bool
    {
        return false;
    }
}


/app/Models/Project.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function timers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Timer::class);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the total time of all timers in the project.
     * returns time in HH:MM:SS format
     */
    public function totalTime()
    {
        $timers = $this->timers()->get();

        $totalTimeSeconds = 0;
        foreach ($timers as $timer) {
            $startTime = Carbon::parse($timer->start_time);
            $endTime = $timer->end_time ? Carbon::parse($timer->end_time) : Carbon::now();

            $diff = $startTime->diffInSeconds($endTime);

            $totalTimeSeconds += $diff;
        }

        $timeHours = sprintf('%02d', floor($totalTimeSeconds / 3600));
        $timeMinutes = sprintf('%02d', floor(($totalTimeSeconds % 3600) / 60));
        $timeSeconds = sprintf('%02d', $totalTimeSeconds % 60);

        return $timeHours . ':' . $timeMinutes . ':' . $timeSeconds;
    }
}



Are you actually using the policy in your controller? The model code is not relevant at all here

Also you can do date math with Carbon. Create intervals with something like $interval = $startTime->diffAsCarbonInterval(), and then add to a total with $total->add($interval). Get the HMS value at the end with $total->format(). https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Laravel Documentation talks about registering Policies or as the doc mention it Policy Auto-Discovery

Instead of manually registering model policies, Laravel can automatically discover policies as long as the model and policy follow standard Laravel naming conventions. Specifically, the policies must be in a Policies directory at or above the directory that contains your models.

This means that Laravel will know your policies without the need or registering it, BUT it's apt to you to use your policies as you please.
In the Authorizing Actions Using Policies section you can find different ways of using the policies :

Via The User Model
Via Controller Helpers
Via Middleware
Via Blade Templates

For example using the user model like this :
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    if ($request->user()->cannot('update', $post)) {
        abort(403);
    }

    // Update the post...
}

